# How to use onSavedInstanceState example please

Tags: android, savestate

I'm confused when it comes down to saving a state. So I know that `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` is called when the activity is about to be destroyed. But how do you store your information in it and bring it back to its original state in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`? I don't understand how this bundle will restore information. It would be helpful if someone can provide an example.
The Dev guide doesn't do a good job of explaining this.

```
public class Conversation extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog progDialog;
    int typeBar;
    TextView text1;
    EditText edit;
    Button respond;
    private String name;
    private String textAtView;
    private String savedName;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.dorothydialog);
        text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog);
        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.repsond);
        respond = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button01);

        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            savedInstanceState.get(savedName);
            text1.setText(savedName);
        }
        else{
            text1.setText("Hello! What is your name?");
            respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    name = edit.getText().toString();
                    text1.setText("Nice to meet you "+ name);
                }   
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(savedName, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: text1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(savedName));

Comment: @Spidy What about onBackpressed? How would i react to this with the bundle?

Comment: You wouldn't. When the user presses the back button. The activity is killed. Use a database for permanent data storage. Use the Bundle for returning a restarted application to its previous state.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

The `Bundle` is a container for all the information you want to save. You use the put* functions to insert data into it. Here's a short list (there are more) of put functions you can use to store data in the `Bundle`.

```
putString
putBoolean
putByte
putChar
putFloat
putLong
putShort
putParcelable (used for objects but they must implement Parcelable)
```

In your `onCreate` function, this `Bundle` is handed back to the program. The best way to check if the application is being reloaded, or started for the first time is:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // Then the application is being reloaded
}
```

To get the data back out, use the get* functions just like the put* functions. The data is stored as a name-value pair. This is like a hashmap. You provide a key and the value, then when you want the value back, you give the key and the function gets the value. Here's a short example.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   outState.putString("message", "This is my message to be reloaded");
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String message = savedInstanceState.getString("message");
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Your saved message will be toasted to the screen.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState() is called before your activity is paused. So any info that it needs after it is potentially destroyed can be retrieved from the saved Bundle

Comment: @Spidy Awesome! You just really made me understand everything about a bundle! so im guessing outState is passed back to the savedInstanceState bundle? Correct?

Comment: Yep. The outState Bundle is passed back in as the savedInstanceState Bundle

Comment: @tj walker - Another great resource are technical reference books. Pro Android 3 is a cheap but extensive resource you can get on Amazon

Comment: @Spidy I posted my activity code above for you to see. Maybe you can let me know if im saving my state right, as you suggested.

Comment: This is how its works, good job. I was actually messing with onSavedInstanceState awhile till I found this and was like, oh thats how it works.

Comment: As suggested by Developer android here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState super should be called after adding more data to the outstate(Bundle). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the order being important. It simple states that you should definitely call super so that the view hierarchy gets saved. I'd imagine for restore its important, since you want the views restored before updating their view data.

Answer (score 36):

One major note that all new Android developers should know is that any information in Widgets (TextView, Buttons, etc.) will be persisted automatically by Android as long as you assign an ID to them.  So that means most of the UI state is taken care of without issue.  Only when you need to store other data does this become an issue.

From [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html):

> The only work required by you is to
>   provide a unique ID (with the
>   android:id attribute) for each widget
>   you want to save its state. If a
>   widget does not have an ID, then it
>   cannot save its state

Comment: Well is that really true? Because i have an activity with a button textview and edit text. If the application is destroyed or killed everything is returned to its original state. In my application the textView texts changes everytime the user clickes the button.

Comment: Is the documentation inaccurate? I've never had a View save its own information. Your best bet is to save all your information yourself in my opinion.

Comment: If your goal is to save information onSaveInstanceState is NOT the place to do it.  That is because there is no guarantee that it will be called (see docs).  You should instead write to a database,  SharedPreferences, etc.  Yes this information is accurate.  The best way to test if your UI is persisting in this fashion is to rotate your display as orientation changes rerun your onCreate and use the bundle to restore state.

Comment: @Nissan Fan can you give an example as spidy did above? With the sharedprefs and all? Thanks

Comment: The best examples quite frankly come from the documentation.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: You are correct. savedInstanceState is only temporary storage used for when the device goes through configuration changes and restarts. For permanent storage of information that should be retained over multiple application launches, database storage should be used.

Answer (score 8):

A good information: you don't need to check whether the Bundle object is null into the onCreate() method. Use the onRestoreInstanceState() method, which the system calls after the onStart() method. The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null

Answer (score 5):

Store information:

```
static final String PLAYER_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String PLAYER_LEVEL = "playerLevel";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(PLAYER_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(PLAYER_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

// Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

If you don't want to restore information in your onCreate-Method:

Here are the examples: [Recreating an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

> Instead of restoring the state during onCreate() you may choose to implement onRestoreInstanceState(), which the system calls after the onStart() method. The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

// Restore state members from saved instance
mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(PLAYER_SCORE);
mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(PLAYER_LEVEL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outBundle) will give you a bundle.
When you look at the Bundle class, you will see that you can put lots of different stuff inside it. At the next call of onCreate(), you just get that Bundle back as an argument.
Then you can read your values again and restore your activity.

Lets say you have an activity with an EditText. The user wrote some text inside it.
After that the system calls your onSaveInstanceState().
You read the text from the EditText and write it into the Bundle via Bundle.putString("edit_text_value", theValue).

Now onCreate is called. You check if the supplied bundle is not null. If thats the case,
you can restore your value via Bundle.getString("edit_text_value") and put it back into your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

This is for extra information.

Imagine this scenario

1. ActivityA launch ActivityB.
2. ActivityB launch a new ActivityAPrime by

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
3. ActivityAPrime has no relationship with ActivityA.
   In this case the Bundle in ActivityAPrime.onCreate() will be null.

If ActivityA and ActivityAPrime should be the same activity instead of different activities, 
ActivityB should call finish() than using startActivity().

Comment: just to clarify, in your example, is ActivityA == ActivityA instance 1 and ActivityAPrime == ActivityA instance 2?

also, when you say, "ActivityB should call finish() than using startActivity()." 

do you mean:
 (1) AcitivityB should call finish() and then use startActivity() afterwards
 (2) or ActivityB should call finish() rather than using startActivity() at all?

if you meant option 2, how would you suggest someone restart the same activityA instance1 so you can load data the activity contained prior to being destroyed/finished? Thanks

Comment: ActivityA and ActivityAPrime are of same class but different instances. In this scenario, ActivityA is not yet finish its business, in the middle of it, it created and started ActivityB, so when ActivityB finish, ActivityA should continue its remaining of business. It is wrong to call startActivity in this case, and expecting ActivityA and ActiviyAPrime to be same instance. so we should not restart of ActivityA, just finish ActivityB and let ActivityA resume its operation...

Answer (score 0):

If Data Is not Loaded From `savedInstanceState` use following code.
 The problem is url call is not to complete fully so, check if data is loaded then to show the instanceState value.

```
//suppose data is not Loaded to savedInstanceState at 1st swipe
if (savedInstanceState == null && !mAlreadyLoaded){
    mAlreadyLoaded = true;
    GetStoryData();//Url Call
} else {
    if (listArray != null) {  //Data Array From JsonArray(ListArray)
        System.out.println("LocalData  " + listArray);
        view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        GetStoryData();//Url Call
    }
}
```