# How can I add a hint to the Spinner widget?

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner, hint

I have a `Spinner` in `spinnerMode="dropdown"` mode. Instead of the preselected first item, I want to show the user a hint, so that there is no default selection (like »Please select an item«)

This is the UI I got:

[image: the current UI]

and this is the UI I want to achive:

[image: the UI I want to achive]

I figured that the `EditText` widget has an `android:hint` attribute, but not the `Spinner` widget and setting it doesn't bring me the the UI I want. This is an Android 4.x-only app, so I don't have to hassle with any pre-4.0 compatibility stuff.

Comment: whether **android:prompt="@String/select"** will work or not.?

Comment: Sadly, no: the prompt is for the dropdown which appears after taping the `Spinner` widget. And further it doesn't work if one uses the Holo-Themes which are new in Android 4.x.

Comment: The spinner adapter has different methods, one for dropdown view and ane for listview with all options. So, when nothing is selected you adapter returns this TextView by default, else the item selected.

Comment: @izaakcito I'll probably go with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12386866/408150. Once I finished it, I'll update this question with my solution.

Comment: https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-spinner-hint.html another good tutorial

Answer (score 24):

I haven't found an easy and clean solution yet, only this workaround using custom adapters and a custom item class:

First, we need a class for the spinner item content:

```
class SpinnerItem {
        private final String text;
        private final boolean isHint;

        public SpinnerItem(String strItem, boolean flag) {
            this.isHint = flag;
            this.text = strItem;
        }

        public String getItemString() {
            return text;
        }

        public boolean isHint() {
            return isHint;
        }
    }
```

Then our adapter class:

```
class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem> {
        public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SpinnerItem> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount() - 1; // This makes the trick: do not show last item
        }

        @Override
        public SpinnerItem getItem(int position) {
            return super.getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }

    }
```

Finally we use the workaround like this:

```
ArrayList<SpinnerItem> items = new ArrayList<SpinnerItem>();
        items.add(new SpinnerItem("Item 1", false));
        items.add(new SpinnerItem("Item 2", false));
        items.add(new SpinnerItem("HINT", true)); // Last item 

        MySpinnerAdapter adapter = new MySpinnerAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(items.size() - 1);
```

Then you can use the flag from the SpinnerItem class to set text color for that item or whatever.

Comment: nice! I like this work-around. Question: what is the color of the hint text in an edit text ?

Comment: looks like the text color of a hint in an edit text is `Color.rgb(148, 150, 148)`

Comment: to set the color of the hint text, I implemented the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` class and within `onItemSelected` it performs `SpinnerItem data = items.get(position);` followed by `if (data.isHint() {do stuff}`

Comment: Thanks that worked like a charm..:) one more thing no need to create separate class (Like SpinnerItem if u wanna use List<String)

Comment: There something wrong with your adapter .. is shows me the package name insted of Values that i gibe to the list ....

Comment: @Oussaki yap i have also faced the same issue ??? are you found the solution ?

Comment: @chhameed yeap i found the solution for this problem ..
just a little change in the adapter ... by setting the count of the items = count-1 and add in the list item the value that you want by default to show up ... it works for me now .. and try to not use his class of item , just use the default items ... that all . if any problem i can feed you with my code . regards .

Comment: This doesn't works in orientation changed. It selects second last item in the list

Comment: hint text not displaying properly it shows the cut texts like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188815/custom-spinner-textview-is-being-cut-off but if i select other item like item.size() - 2 it works fine

Comment: @Oussaki can you share the code on how you fixed it?

Comment: @DiegoRivera Read my last comment.