# Custom Spinner TextView is being cut off

Tags: android, textview, spinner, android-spinner

So in the attached screen shot and the code sample you can see my custom spinner. As you can see my text is getting cut off no matter what I try to do. The nine patch image is set up correctly with the text padding on it too.  I have right just about everything and am at a complete loss...

Custom spinner

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/spinner"
android:textColor="#555"
android:textSize="22sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:typeface="normal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="40sp"
android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
android:singleLine="true" />
```

Implementing custom spinner

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_both20"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b_both20"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b_both20"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_both20"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    android:padding="20sp" />
```

Java

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aBoth = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.d20both, R.layout.spinner_settings)
```

I'm super frustrated to be spending this many hours on something so simple. Any help would rock!

[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove the padding in your spinner?

Comment: So how after spending hours looking at this I never noticed that there was that padding line... I feel dumb and thanks for the help :S

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a 2nd set of eyes. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding will cut cut into your inner text.