# Show default value in Spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

I want to show a dropdown for gender selection. I passed a string array as

```
String arr[]=new String[]{"male","female"};
```

but the problem is that is shows default selection with the value of `"male"` and I want to show `"Gender"` as default value. If I pass "Gender" in array at position 0, then it is visible in dropdown also. I just want "Gender" as hint but it must not be shown in dropdown.

How can this be done?

Comment: [Check this same question is asked here][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one

Comment: Could you please make a screenshot of your desired design? Thanks

Answer (score 67):

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
sp.setSelection(pos);
```

here pos is integer (your array item position)

array is like below then `pos = 0;`

```
String str[] = new String{"Select Gender","male", "female" };
```

then in onItemSelected

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> main, View view, int position,
            long Id) {

        if(position > 0){
          // get spinner value
        }else{
          // show toast select gender
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution by extending `ArrayAdapter` and Overriding the `getView` method.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A SpinnerAdapter which does not show the value of the initial selection initially,
 * but an initialText.
 * To use the spinner with initial selection instead call notifyDataSetChanged().
 */
public class SpinnerAdapterWithInitialText<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    private Context context;
    private int resource;

    private boolean initialTextWasShown = false;
    private String initialText = "Please select";

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context The current context.
     * @param resource The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when
     *                 instantiating views.
     * @param objects The objects to represent in the ListView.
     */
    public SpinnerAdapterWithInitialText(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull T[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the user has selected a spinner item, or if still the initial text is shown.
     * @param spinner The spinner the SpinnerAdapterWithInitialText is assigned to.
     * @return true if the user has selected a spinner item, false if not.
     */
    public boolean selectionMade(Spinner spinner) {
        return !((TextView)spinner.getSelectedView()).getText().toString().equals(initialText);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a TextView with the initialText the first time getView is called.
     * So the Spinner has an initialText which does not represent the selected item.
     * To use the spinner with initial selection instead call notifyDataSetChanged(),
     * after assigning the SpinnerAdapterWithInitialText.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View recycle, ViewGroup container) {
        if(initialTextWasShown) {
            return super.getView(position, recycle, container);
        } else {
            initialTextWasShown = true;
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(resource, container, false);

            ((TextView) view).setText(initialText);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

What Android does when initialising the Spinner, is calling getView for the selected item before calling getView for all items in `T[] objects`.
The `SpinnerAdapterWithInitialText` returns a `TextView` with the `initialText`, the first time it is called.
All the other times it calls `super.getView` which is the `getView` method of `ArrayAdapter` which is called if you are using the Spinner normally.

To find out whether the user has selected a spinner item, or if the spinner still displays the `initialText`, call `selectionMade` and hand over the spinner the adapter is assigned to.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but you must add a validation for the 0 pos selection, spinner doesn't take it as selection if it remains at 0 so it won't change the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Spinner don't support Hint, i recommend you to make a custom spinner adapter.

check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13878692/1725748

Comment: Spinner doesn't support hint? What about `promt` then?

Answer (score -7):

Try below:

```
   <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/YourSpinnerId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="Gender" />
```