# How to add default value in Spinner other then adapter Value

Tags: android, android-activity, android-spinner

i have some data coming from server and i have to show that value in Android Spinner.
Adapter that is attach to Spinner also getiing from server.
please let me know how to show initial value coming from server.and show adapter value after click on Spinner.

```
 Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.householdspinner);

         mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Edit_Voter_Information.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                            householdIncome));


            mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                                   View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

                            String item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            house_Hold_Income = item;



                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: Duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063611/show-default-value-in-spinner-in-android

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602339/android-spinner-hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially i stored some values in String[] names. when activity is run spinner position 0(zero)is selected by default.
Check my code below:

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_style, names);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();//which returns names[0] initially.

if click other position(i) it returns names[i], where i =0,1,2,..