# how to change default text for spinners

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using three spinners in my code, I assigned an single array to three spinners but I want to change the default text of the three spinners.I getting array details in the spinners.

```
Spinner sp1,sp2,sp3;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrer_seq);
    apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.current, R.layout.spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp1.setPrompt("Developers(2-3 years)");
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp2.setPrompt("Senior Developers(4-5 years)");
    sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp3.setPrompt("Project Lead(6-7 years)");
    sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textColorHint="@color/text"
    android:textColor="#808080"/>
```

Comment: have you tried these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476665/how-to-change-spinner-text-size-and-text-color

Comment: yes i tried but here i want to change my three spinners default text only.

Comment: Did u try above link....Or you are not getting on it??

Comment: yes its not getting on it. it getting the contents in array

Comment: have you create the custom layout for the spinner?

Comment: There is no prompt displayed on a spinner on Honeycomb and later, that's why you can't see any effect of the `setPrompt` method. If you want to change the "default text", you will have to incorporate them into the spinner's value array. You'll have to implement it yourself, see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063611/show-default-value-in-spinner-in-android#answer-17063675).

Comment: @HeamanthVarma ... DId u resolve your problem??

Comment: getting an error on sp1.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, R.array.current, "Developers")); at R.array.current it is a int resource and in customer spinner adapter it is a java.lang.string

Comment: I think after Icecream sandwich version, setPrompt is not working in spinnerMode "dropdown", it is working in spinnerMode "dialog".

Comment: hey after adding sp1.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.current), "Developers(2-3 years)")); this code in my class i got it thank you @ravindra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these below line of code

```
  Spinner sp1,sp2,sp3;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrer_seq);
    apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

   sp1.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, YOUR_ARRYLIST, "Developers(2-3 years)"));

   sp2.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, YOUR_ARRYLIST, "Senior Developers(4-5 years)"));

   sp3.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_row, YOUR_ARRYLIST, "Project Lead(6-7 years)"));
```

And than after create the custom adapter for it

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

Context context;
String[] objects;
String firstElement;
boolean isFirstTime;

public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, String defaultText) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
    this.isFirstTime = true;
    setDefaultText(defaultText);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(isFirstTime) {
        objects[0] = firstElement;
        isFirstTime = false;
    }
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
    this.firstElement = objects[0];
    objects[0] = defaultText;
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
    TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_text);
    label.setText(objects[position]);

    return row;
}

}
```

Comment: I want to change the default text not color.

Comment: Sorry bro....@HeamanthVarma ... For not getting you... what default text , you want to set on the spinner??

Comment: yes I want to set the default texts of my three spinners as spinners as above in the code as developers,seniors and project lead. those three spinners have same details but i have to change only the default text.

Comment: On the first item of the arraylist...you can add these string respectively on their ARRYLIST...And try it...

Comment: the array_list is same to the three spinners but default text should be change.

Comment: Right now , what is the by default test is it showing??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
    current.add("value1");
    current.add("value2");
    current.add("value3");

    current.add("Choose Size"); //adding String at the end of ArrayList
    Collections.reverse(current); //Last Item Will Be Shown As A Spinner Title

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sizes);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

*** You have to add the value at last as :

```
 current.add("Choose Size");
```

and then reverse the array before set adapter.