# Spinner Default text while the values in spinner are from database

Tags: java, android, database, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I need a default text for a spinner where values in the spinner are from database,fetching all details from database into spinner by using arrayadapter,but im not able to apply default text like Select Size for it. Isaw many posts ,but i didnt find one which has same requirement.
Help me please :( Here is the code

```
String siz =feedObj.getString("P_Size");
Size=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.size);
if(siz!= null && !siz.isEmpty())
{
String[] seperatedsize = siz.split(", ");     
ArrayAdapter spinnersize = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,seperatedsize);
spinnersize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Size.setAdapter(spinnersize);
//  spinnersize.add("select");
//  spinnersize.setPrompt("Select your Size!");
}
else
{   
layoutsize.setVisibility(View.GONE);
Size.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

here is the image

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIi16.png)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this handy's posts posted on Stack Overflow you got what you want.

1. [Show default value in Spinner in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063611/show-default-value-in-spinner-in-android)
2. [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

Comment: Hello,thanks for the answer ,the links you provided ( i tried them but no use they are showing only default text which i can also do ) but i want both (default text + database values ).like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one (3rd post images) here he is getting data from strings ,but here i want data from database which has default text.any help?

Comment: @aayviD I think you are talking about something like this>   like there are 5,6,or soon values coming from database and you need one value at the top of the list in your spinner. If it is so then you may need to add a defaut value in the list when you have completed fetching your values from db. If is not then please elaborate your question may be i have understood something different

Comment: I have a field named P_Size in Database ,and in that i have values (SS,XS,XXL,XL).I need all those values to be in my spinner(i did that) and also default text at the top .

Answer (score 0):

```
if(siz!= null && !siz.isEmpty())
{
String[] seperatedsize = siz.split(", ");
**StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("Select your Size!").append(",");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    stringBuilder.append(arr[i]).append(",");
}
String strTemp=sb.toString();
seperatedsize=strTemp.split(",");**     
ArrayAdapter spinnersize = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,seperatedsize);
spinnersize.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Size.setAdapter(spinnersize);
//  spinnersize.add("select");
//  spinnersize.setPrompt("Select your Size!");
}
```

You can try this out.

or

you can use `ArrayList<String>` to hold your data.After storing data in array list just call add(0,"Select your Size!") with `ArrayList<String>` object.

Demo code :

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("b");
arrayList.add("c");
arrayList.add("d");
arrayList.add("e");
arrayList.add("f");
arrayList.add(0, "a");
```

Result : a,b,c,d,e,f