# Why is the 'prompt' of the android spinner not shown?

Tags: android

In android I define a layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar_setting"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/settings_interval"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>

      ...
```

But some some reason the `android:promp` text for the spinner is not shown  when I start the corresponding activity. For completeness here is that activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.settings);

         // Set toolbar, allow going back.
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_setting);
         //toolbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         //toolbar.setTitle("Settings");
         setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");

         Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.settings_interval);
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.listValues, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);    
     }
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same issue I am having!!

Comment: what spinner mode you are using ? dialog or dropdown??

Comment: paste that line to spinner tag and check android:spinnerMode="dialog"

Comment: I guess dropdown? Please look at the code...

Comment: default is dropdown mode. change it to dialog then prompt will be show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code from `Spinner` class:

```
public void setPromptText(CharSequence hintText) {
    // Hint text is ignored for dropdowns, but maintain it here.
    mHintText = hintText;
}
```

It looks like spinner ignore prompt in dropDown mode. Try to set     `android:spinnerMode="dialog"` to check.

Also you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877681/how-can-i-add-a-hint-to-the-spinner-widget) to solve this.