# Can anyone help me to set spinner value to null or to hint?

Tags: android, spinner

how do I set the spinner value to null or to a hint when it is not on click..? Because when I set spinner's adapter it appears in the spinner textfield even Im not selecting a specific dropdown item.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert first item with "" (empty string) value in your ArrayList or Array.

Comment: i want to do it dynamically not by setting up in array.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any data in the adapter in the spinner then it will show that data. So in this case it is not possible to show empty spinner.

In your case My suggestion is, use a entry like none/no selection in your spinner at the very first index. So that it will automatically show that. Also user can select no selection option from the spinner also.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate.

You could create the illusion of the spinner by styling a button like below.
`android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"`

see [here] for alternatives. ([Android: Spinner hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602339/android-spinner-hint))

Answer (score 0):

On the onItemSelected:
((TextView)view).setText(null);

By using this, Spinner will not show any default value.