# Can we give hint to a spinner whose data is coming programmatically from the database?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am working on a spinner in which I am getting values of the spinner from the database.

I want to add hint to this spinner...and the problem arising is that I cannot able to add hint to this spinner.

What should I do?...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a costum adapter for your spinner. There are some tutorials on the web:

[Android: Spinner hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602339/android-spinner-hint)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make an initial text in spinner. You can do it in many ways

[How to make an Android Spinner with initial text “Select One”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

Otherwise you can use a button instead of spinner and create a dialog when button clicked

Comment: If I make initial text as "Select One"..by default it will take this value in database..I want the hint should be in such a manner that when i select spinner then only it works...what happening now is that if am not selecting spinner, its by default taking the first value which I don't want.

Comment: so just use a button with dialog, and populate the database in dialog

Comment: no it wont, i did this tutorial too and the text "Select One" ist just a text in the spinner. The items from database are populated in activities not in the adapter.

Comment: public SpinnerHintAdapter(Context context, ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter, String hintText, int nothingSelectedLayout)....         hint and the populating items are different things

Comment: make hint in background(In xml as android:text) or make it through programitically

Comment: Even after giving hint, without selecting spinner, it is taking first value bydefault as checked in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a little component to get this. Just add a hint text in AutoCompleteTexview and build CompleteSpinner with it

https://github.com/FernandoGaliay/CompleteSpinner