# Add Spinner Hint that has data from json

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner

i populate spinner from json data, I want to set  hint so that user can under stand what has to be selected since when there is no internet connection spinner show no sign of what to be selected.Some answer have suggested to use prompt

```
 <Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:prompt="@string/country_prompt"
    />
```

and other suggested the use of the use of last index of spinner as hint like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019941/how-to-add-a-hint-in-spinner-in-xml).How can i set something like hint or related to so that user can understand what spinner is all about even the moment app is off line. Below is my code snipe from  [here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/)

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
        world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner 
        worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        // JSON file URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt");

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

                worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("rank"));
                worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("country"));
                worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("population"));
                worldpop.setFlag(jsonobject.optString("flag"));
                world.add(worldpop);

                // Populate spinner with country names
                worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("country"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                        TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
                        TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
                        TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);

                        // Set the text followed by the position 
                        txtrank.setText("Rank : "
                                + world.get(position).getRank());
                        txtcountry.setText("Country : "
                                + world.get(position).getCountry());
                        txtpopulation.setText("Population : "
                                + world.get(position).getPopulation());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your hind in ArrayList 0 index first it will be get displayed:

```
    worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    worldlist.add("Your first hint");
```

For last hint add after for loop your hint:

```
try{
    for(......){

  }
  worldlist.add("Your last hint");
 }catch(Exception e){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
    // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

//add a check if worldlist is empty. Initialize it where you have declared it.
if(!worldlist.size() > 0){
    worldlist.add(“select country”);
}

// Spinner adapter
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, worldlist));

//your rest of the code here. . .
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
            world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner 
            worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            worldlist.add("Selct Country");
            // JSON file URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt");

            try {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

                    worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("rank"));
                    worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("country"));
                    worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("population"));
                    worldpop.setFlag(jsonobject.optString("flag"));
                    world.add(worldpop);

                    // Populate spinner with country names
                    worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("country"));

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                        if(position > 0){
                        TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
                        TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
                        TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);

                        // Set the text followed by the position 
                        txtrank.setText("Rank : "
                                + world.get(position).getRank());
                        txtcountry.setText("Country : "
                                + world.get(position).getCountry());
                        txtpopulation.setText("Population : "
                                + world.get(position).getPopulation());
                            }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update with this code,add your hint on arrays 0 posotion.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
        world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        // Create an array to populate the spinner 
        worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        worldlist.add(0,"your hint");
        // JSON file URL address
        jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/jsonparsetutorial.txt");

        try {
            // Locate the NodeList name
            jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

                worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("rank"));
                worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("country"));
                worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("population"));
                worldpop.setFlag(jsonobject.optString("flag"));
                world.add(worldpop);

                // Populate spinner with country names
                worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("country"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
        // Locate the spinner in activity_main.xml
        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

        // Spinner adapter
        mySpinner
                .setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
                        worldlist));

        // Spinner on item click listener
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                            View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Locate the textviews in activity_main.xml
                        TextView txtrank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
                        TextView txtcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
                        TextView txtpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);

                        // Set the text followed by the position 
                        txtrank.setText("Rank : "
                                + world.get(position).getRank());
                        txtcountry.setText("Country : "
                                + world.get(position).getCountry());
                        txtpopulation.setText("Population : "
                                + world.get(position).getPopulation());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
    }
}
```