# How to add Hint in Spinner widget populated with data from FireBase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner, hint

My xml code is :

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/destination"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:autofillHints="Choose destination"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />
```

I want to add hint (without using dummy entry) as to be shown to user when the activity starts.
The inbuilt xml hint feature is not working after using FireBase.

MainActivity :

```
myRef.child("Stations").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> stationname = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot stationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                 String stationName = stationSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                 stationname.add(stationName);
            }

            Spinner sp2= findViewById(R.id.destination);

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FairPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stationname);
            arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            sp2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Maybe my answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019941/how-to-add-a-hint-in-spinner-in-xml/53807755#53807755

Comment: It was good brother, I had too solved that issue a while ago. Thanks for your answer @MurilloComino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
myRef.child("Stations").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final List<String> stationname = new ArrayList<String>();
        stationname.add("Select Station");
        for (DataSnapshot stationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

             String stationName = stationSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
             stationname.add(stationName);
        }

        Spinner sp2= findViewById(R.id.destination);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FairPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stationname);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sp2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

and also check when spinner item selected

```
if (stationname.get(postion).equals("Select Station"){
//Toast please  select station 
}
```

Comment: It worked buddy. Edit your answer please, you misspelled some keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one item in array list before setting the data from firebase. As done -

```
stationname.add("Select Station"); // hint 
myRef.child("Stations").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final List<String> stationname = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (DataSnapshot stationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

             String stationName = stationSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
             stationname.add(stationName);
        }

        Spinner sp2= findViewById(R.id.destination);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FairPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stationname);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        sp2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: had to add the dummy station name after initialing List<String> stationname

Comment: stationname.add(" ") line should be after initializing stationname. Correct logic bdw. Thank you.