# I want to add "Select One" in the first position of the custom spinner where custom data is filling through a arraylist

Tags: android

> Added Spinner data

```
 ProductSpinnerAdapter productSpinnerAdapter = new ProductSpinnerAdapter(context, brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductDetailsArrayList());
 holder.spinner_product_details.setAdapter(productSpinnerAdapter);
```

> When change to this

```
ProductDetails selectOneDetails = new  ProductDetails("", "Select One", "", "0.00", "", "", "");
    ArrayList productDetails = brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductDetailsArrayList();
    productDetails.add(0, selectOneDetails);


    ProductSpinnerAdapter productSpinnerAdapter = new ProductSpinnerAdapter(context, productDetails);
    holder.spinner_product_details.setAdapter(productSpinnerAdapter);
```

*When i update my code i am getting selec one but in the every selection of the spinner Select one is added *

Comment: I have added spinner data in the spinner but want to add Some hint in the spinner as select one in the first position

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019941/how-to-add-a-hint-in-spinner-in-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an Android Spinner with initial text "Select One"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867518/how-to-make-an-android-spinner-with-initial-text-select-one)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `add(index, element)` **interface method** , i.e, `list.add(index, element)`

```
 brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductDetailsArrayList().add(0, "Select One");
```

Comment: Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'com.argosupplier.Bean.ProductDetails' less... 
Inspection info:
add
(int,
com.argosupplier.Bean.ProductDetails)
in ArrayList cannot be applied
to
(int,
java.lang.String)

Comment: you need to construct the `ProductDetails` element ! with the string "Select One" and then use it

Comment: Can't get it. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **Select One** as first child of **productDetails** items

```
ProductDetails selectOneDetails = ProductDetails("", "Select One", "", "", "", "", "") 
ArrayList productDetails = brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductDetailsArrayList();
productDetails.add(0, selectOneDetails);
ProductSpinnerAdapter productSpinnerAdapter = new ProductSpinnerAdapter(context, productDetails);
holder.spinner_product_details.setAdapter(productSpinnerAdapter);
```

You can modified **selectOneDetails** object by passing appropriate data to `ProductDetails` constructor.

Comment: in the adapter section of load spinner. 

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.argosupplier.Bean.ProductDetails
        at com.argosupplier.Adapter.ProductSpinnerAdapter.initView(ProductSpinnerAdapter.java:71)
        at com.argosupplier.Adapter.ProductSpinnerAdapter.getView(ProductSpinnerAdapter.java:52)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:193)

Comment: Then add your **ProductDetails** model, I will update my code. Or You have to create a **ProductDetails** object with **Select One**

Comment: public ProductDetails(String id, String name, String pn, String comRate, String nettRate, String rateWithGST, String pkgNo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pn = pn;
        this.comRate = comRate;
        this.nettRate = nettRate;
        this.rateWithGST = rateWithGST;
        this.pkgNo = pkgNo;
    }

Comment: Thats the Constractor of my ProductDetails  model class

Comment: but why to avoid selectOneDetails  multiple times, Its getting multiple

Comment: You have to add more code to check that. How can I know from where you call this? If you call this multiple time then it adds multiple time. You have to check that

Comment: NO No when i am selecting any spinner item from spinner then automatically select one is incresasing

Comment: only first position of the arraylist is increasing rather than that its fine.

Comment: That is another issue. Its depends on your implementation. Accept this answer and post another with the problem mentioning some code. Thanks

Comment: My code was running successfully before add "Select One". Again when I omit this "Select One" then its work fine

Comment: Hi sir is there any way to validate the spinner

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
String[] newArrayList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourArrayName);
List<String> listNew = new ArrayList<String>();
listNew.add("Select One");
for (int j = 0; j < newArrayList.length; j++) {
    listNew.add(newArrayList[j]);
}
```

Than pass new List to spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this

1. Add a element on first position if user selects first do nothing
2. Use Library Spinners 'https://github.com/srodrigo/Android-Hint-Spinner' like this will provides additional tag of hint.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way you can add.

```
ArrayList<String> newBrandList = new ArrayList()<>;
    newBrandList.add("Select One");
    ArrayList<brandModel> brandWiseProductArrayList = brandWiseProductArrayList.get(position).getProductDetailsArrayList()
    for(int i=0 i<brandWiseProductArrayList.size();i++){
    newBrandList.add(brandWiseProductArrayList.get(i).value);
    }

    ProductSpinnerAdapter productSpinnerAdapter = new ProductSpinnerAdapter(context, brandWiseProductArrayList);
     holder.spinner_product_details.setAdapter(productSpinnerAdapter);
```

or you can add on index 0

```
brandWiseProductArrayList = brandWiseProductArrayList.add(0,"Select One");
```

Comment: brandWiseProductArrayList  is not string

Comment: then simple create array of your model get detail array and add detail array indexes in new array list check my edited answer