# How to hide first item in an android spinner dropdown?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using adapter.add for adding a title in my spinner, but how to hide first item in an android spinner dropdown?
Here is My Code:

```
var spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
spinner1.Adapter = adapter;
adapter.Add("Select one...");
adapter.Add("Name");
adapter.Add("Mobile");
adapter.Add("Age");
```

See images below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You mean you want to remove `Select one` from *spinner* when *popup* opens ? Please elaborate more.

Comment: I think you might be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602339/android-spinner-hint)

Comment: Yes i mean remove.