# Which Android Data Storage Technique to use?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sharedpreferences, data-storage

The android documentation has the following options below but does not explain what circumstances each is best for. What are the pros and cons of each method? e.g. Under what conditions would SQL be better than Shared Preferences?

- Shared Preferences
- Internal Storage
- External Storage
- SQLite Databases
- Network Connection

Comment: For information it might be good to know that `onSavedInstanceState` is also a data persistence technique in Android though it doesn't survive doesn't app or phone restarts. It can be used to restore activity state when activity gets destroyed and restarts later. Few details - [How to use onSavedInstanceState example please](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6525698/465053) & [When exactly are onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20831826/465053)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

### Different Storage options in Android

[image]

---

### Content Providers

[image]

- Consider the structured data added to the device from application1 is
  not accessible to another application2 present in the same device but
  the profile photo added to the device by `application1` is available to
  the `application2` running in the same device
- Consider android device as a city, the applications in it are the
  houses in the city, people in the houses(application) are the  data.
  Now content provider is like an broker in the city(android device).
  This broker provide access for the people in the city for finding
  different houses referring as the content provider in the android
  device provide access for the data in the device for different
  applications.

---

### Shared Preferences

[image]

- Consider I have an App say a Face book App which I use to log in to
  my account.
- Now the very first time I enter my username and password to get
  access to my account. Say I log out of the application an hour later
  again I use the same Face book App to login again to my application.
- I have to enter username and password again to login to my account
  and I set a theme to my application and other settings on how my app
  looks in my current phone
- This is un-necessary because consider I am using my phone to login to
  the application. So I will always use my phone to login again and
  again, thus entering my credentials again and again is more work
  shows it’s not a user friendly app
- Shared Preferences is very handy in such scenarios where I can use
  its feature to share my data in a xml file Which physically exists in
  the Android app installed in my phone which is not destroyed even if
  the app is closed. Here we can save user preferences data of the
  current application.
- As a result next time I open my app in my phone I can see the data
  automatically filled in the necessary fields and the settings are

---

### File Storage

[image]

- In Android we can use the device storage space to store the data in
  it for the applications. The type of data involves things such as a
  text file, image file, video file, audio file etc.
- As seen in the figure as we can see that there are two places we can
  do this. One way is to write the raw files into primary /secondary
  storage. Another way is to write the cache files into the
  primary/secondary storage.
- There is also difference between storing raw data and the cache data,
  the raw data once stored in memory by user has to be explicitly
  deleted by the user explicitly otherwise it would exist till then.
  Cache data stored in memory is not a permanent data because the
  system automatically deletes it if it feels there is shortage of
  memory.

[image]

**Internal Storage:**

- Consider a user in an application has stored data in internal
  storage, then only that user of that application has access to that
  data on the mobile and that data is automatically deleted when the
  user uninstalls the application. Speaking of which internal memory is
  private.
- The apps internal storage directory is stored using the name package
  name in a special place in the android file system.
- Other apps or users of current app have no access to the file set by
  a particular user and a particular app unless it is explicitly made
  available to the user for readable/writable access.

[image]

---

### SQLite

[image]

- Sqlite is used to store more structured data locally in a mobile
  where the android app is running. Structured data involves as of
  which shown in the figure like a student’s information in the form of
  rows and columns.
- Sqlite offers similar functionality like Mysql and oracle but with
  limited functional features. Some of the things involve performing
  query operations on tables. There are features though like creating
  views but also some features are not available like stored procedure.
- Sqlite is very helpful in storing complex and large data which can be
  downloaded once and can be used again and again until the application
  is running. When the application is closed the sqlite database is
  also destroyed.

---

### Putting all the pieces together

[image]

Comment: SQLite data is destroyed only when the application is uninstalled or "Settings>Clear Data" is pressed, but not when the app is closed.

Comment: will also delete the data from memory if stored any as stated by @b1izzard

Comment: I think this could be a guide or similar like "How to answer to a stackoverflow question". It's not an answer, it's a lesson. Many thanks bro!

Comment: Ámen, this is just like the bible for storing data in Android.

Comment: This is a great answer. Is there a source for the images?

Comment: @MGDavies ... I created the images in MS-PowePoint :)

Answer (score 38):

- **Shared preferences** are good for storing ... an application's preferences, and other small bits of data. It's a just really simple persistent string key store for a few data types: boolean, float, int, long and string. So for instance if my app had a login, I might consider storing the session key as string within SharedPreferences.
- **Internal storage** is good for storing application data that the user doesn't need access to, because the user cannot easily access internal storage. Possibly good for caching, logs, other things. Anything that only the app intends to Create Read Update or Delete.
- **External storage**. Great for the opposite of what I just said. The dropbox app probably uses external storage to store the user's dropbox folder, so that the user has easy access to these files outside the dropbox application, for instance, using the file manager.
- **SQLite** databases are great whenever you are going to use a lot of structured data and a relatively rigid schema for managing it. Put in layman's terms, SQLite is like MySQL or PostgreSQL except instead of the database acting as a server daemon which then takes queries from the CGI scripts like php, it is simply stored in a .db file, and accessed and queried through a simple library within the application. While SQLite cannot scale nearly as big as the dedicated databases, it is very quick and convenient for smaller applications, like Android apps. I would use an SQLite db if I were making an app for aggregating and downloading recipes, since that kind of data is relatively structured and a database would allow for it to scale well. Databases are nice because writing all of your data to a file, then parsing it back in your own proprietary format it no fun. Then again, storing data in XML or JSON wouldn't be so bad.
- **Network connection** refers to storing data on the cloud. HTTP or FTP file and content transfers through the java.net.* packages makes this happen.

Comment: How about content provider?

Comment: ContentProvider is a scheme/interface for providing data to other apps; it doesn't directly involve the actual storage of the data itself, although generally they will be backed by a database.

Comment: Thank you for laying this out in so much detail (and thanks matt5784 for the ContentProvider tidbit).

Comment: Expanding on the comment about XML or JSON for storing structured data in a file: For XML, see android.util.xml classes. For JSON, google "JSON in Java". Either is useful if you are planning on reading/writing moderately complex data all at once, into java objects. (If too much data to load into memory all at once, then use SQLite database instead. Likewise, if parts of the data are changing frequently, probably better to write each changed part back to DB.) For some programmers, XML or JSON will be more comfortable than database schemas + SQL queries.

Answer (score 16):

**SharedPreferences** is mainly for application-specific settings that you can access via your Settings menu - like application settings. It's a good idea to keep everything simple here - mostly boolean flags, short strings, or integers. SharedPreferences data persist on device reboot, and are removed along with app uninstallation. Data is saved as a key-value pair.

**Internal Storage** is mostly used for larger non-persistent data storage. You utilize internal storage if you want to *process* an image, a short video clip, a large text file, etc. But you don't store the processed data in the internal storage - its function is more like a CPU's RAM. The amount of available internal storage for your application depends on the device, but it's always a good idea to keep anything under 1MB. Data is referenced via its file path.

**External Storage** does not only refer to the SDCard storage, but for higher-end phones, this can mean internal mountable storage (like in the Galaxy Nexus or S2). This is where you store the large video files, the high-resolution images, and the 20-megabyte text file you want to parse in your application. This is also a place to store data that you want shared across devices if you swap sd cards. Data is also referenced via its file path.

**SQLite Databases** is where you'd store pretty much anything you want in a regular database - with the advantage of organizing things into tables, rows, and columns. It works best with things that you want displayed in the UI as lists - the best example would be the great invention knows as the CursorAdapter. Data stored here also persist on device reboot, and are removed with app uninstallation. You can also share data across applications with sqlite db if you hook it up to a ContentProvider. Data is accessed using a [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), where you can call methods as if you're executing sql statements.

**Network Connection** is not really a data storage technique, but can be a way of persisting data for a specific user provided the device is connected to the internet, using some sort of authentication. You have to balance out between downloading data every time the app needs it, or having a one-time data sync, which would ultimately lead to another of the storage options mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Shared preferences are key/value pairs, nothing more.  So if you want to keep track of say, students and their test score, it really won't work well for that.

A database is just that, a database.  You can define as many columns (and tables) as you need to get the job done.

If it's preferences for your app, use shared preferences (almost any preference I can think of can be done that way), if it's anything else more complicated, use a database.