# Android go back to previous activity with previous bundle/extras

Tags: java, android

I have Activity #1: and I move to #Activity 2

**Activity1:**

```
Intent PostLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class);
        PostLogin.putExtra("email",emailOfUser);
        PostLogin.putExtra("token", authToken);
        PostLogin.putExtra("url", url);
        startActivity(PostLogin);
```

**Activity #2:**

```
ONCREATE ACTIVITY 2:


Intent loginActivity = getIntent();
        token = loginActivity.getStringExtra("token");
        email = loginActivity.getStringExtra("email");
        url = loginActivity.getStringExtra("url");


MOVING TO ACTIVITY 3

 Intent createOrJoin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity3.class);
            createOrJoin.putExtra("token", token);
            createOrJoin.putExtra("url",url );
           // createOrJoin.putExtra("token", );
            startActivity(createOrJoin);
```

**ACTIVITY 3 MOVING BACK TO ACTIVITY 2**

```
Intent backtoPost = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class);
                        startActivity(backtoPost);
                        finish();
```

So I initially have info in Activity 2 I got from Activity 1. Then from Activity 2 I go to Activity 3, where after some stuff I come **back** to Activity 2.

How can I still have the values of `token, email, url`?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

1. One simple way is that you can have them in a variable.

   ```
   public class YourActivity extends Activity {

       String email;

       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate();
           // Set content view etc
           email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Another better way is to save those variables that you need when `onSaveInstancestate` is called and then restore them in `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstance`. Check following questions for details: [onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate) and  [When are onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() called, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831826/when-are-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-called-exactly) for how to use them.