# Is it okay to check for saveInstanceState on Destroy?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

in my app, I perform an action `onDestroy`. But I don't want the action if the app is rotated. I used `onSaveInstanceState` to save variables when the app is rotated and check if `saveInstanceState != null` `onCreate`.

I have not seen anyone check for `saveInstanceState` `onDestroy`, is it okay to do that?

Comment: `onDestoy()` not meant to call each time . You should do it in `onSaveInstanceState`..

Comment: Take a read [Activity OnDestroy never called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449955/activity-ondestroy-never-called).

Comment: Possible duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20831826/when-exactly-are-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-called

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee to everytime onDestroy method called.

onSaveInstanceState() was called immediately before onPause() as per documentation

so it not okey to check for saveInstanceState on Destroy.