# Passing Object with multiple parts from one activity to another

Tags: android, object, android-intent, android-activity

Hi I have a Requirement like Person Details for that i have multiple details like personal,educational,job like In first activity am enter personal details and then educational and then job like that one after another for that how can i maintain all details in single object and pass through app please help me.

[image]

Comment: You basically answered your own question- put these values into objects of a class that you create!

Comment: I dont know how to do so thats why am asking some suggestion.Plese try to understand with out give negative click.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you need to bundle an object in an `Intent`, that object must implement the `Parcelable` interface. Here's a common implementation taken from the [Parcelable documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html)...

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     private MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

Once you've done that, simply pass the object around in an `Intent`...

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ACTIVITY_TO_START.class);
i.putExtra("extra_key", new MyParcelable());
startActivity(i);
```

to retrieve the object for the starting activity...

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null && extras.containsKey("extra_key"))
{
    MyParcelable p = (MyParecelable)extras.getParcelable("extra_key");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Simple solution: Use intents for this***

---

**Personal.class**

```
public class Personal extends Activity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.personal);

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Educational.class);
        i.putExtra("personal_details",<-get data from object->);
        startActivity(i);
    } 
}
```

**Educational.class**

```
public class Personal extends Activity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.personal);

        String personal_details; 

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
        personal_details= extras.getString("personal_details");
        } 

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), educational.class);
        i.putExtra("personal_details",personal_details);
        i.putExtra("educational_details",<-get data from object->);
        startActivity(i);
    } 
}
```

**Job.class**

```
public class Personal extends Activity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.personal);

        String personal_details,educational_details; 

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
        personal_details= extras.getString("personal_details");
        educational_details= extras.getString("educational_details");
        } 

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FinalResult.class);
        i.putExtra("personal_details",personal_details);
        i.putExtra("educational_details",educational_details);
        i.putExtra("job_details",<-get data from object->);
        startActivity(i);
    } 
}
```

**FinalResult.class**

```
public class Personal extends Activity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.personal);
        String personal_details,educational_details,job_details; 

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
        personal_details= extras.getString("personal_details");
        educational_details= extras.getString("educational_details");
        job_details= extras.getString("job_details");
        } 
    } 
}
```

---

### {EDIT-1}

- have a look at one of my answers in [***different storage options in
  android - Click Here***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26333317/1083093)
- You can achieve it using `application variable` or `shared
  preferences` but i would not recommend it. !
- Try storing it in POJO(Plain old Java class)

### {EDIT-2}

**Hmm if i understand correctly your question**:: You are connected to internet(Wifi,Wired,... etc) basically you are trying to show a dialog when there is no network connectivity ! .... You can take the help of `Broadcast receivers` ...

**Try this::** Set the broadcast receiver to fire the intent when there is no net connectivity .... 
Write the code to catch that intent and pop the `dialog` .... In this dialog give the user option to reconnect the connectivity !

Comment: thanks for your reply is any way to use global object for saving all details in one userdetails Object and update all details to that object only

Comment: Thanks For Knowledge sharing.I have a doubt regarding network connection.While submitting data to server before submitting am checking network is connected or not if no network is there am showing user alert to set internet.for example am connected to live working wifi network working fine.if some problem with network is not respond but devise is connected to wifi i hope you can understand my question.in that situations wifi is connected but not alive how can i show alert that situations for example in facebook..could not load data thing like that