# Host sqlite database on a third-party cloud-host for an android app

Tags: android, sqlite, google-drive-api, cloud, dropbox

I have an android app that searches through a local stored sqlite database. I want to keep making changes to the database when the app is done so I was thinking about to let the android app sync the database file via an online filehost.

So I want to keep everything as cheap as possible (preferably free) and I was wondering if it is possible to host this database file on a cloud-host like ***Google Drive*** or ***Dropbox*** and let the app sync when there is a new version available.

Could this work? Would this be very slow, illegal or be limited to a certain download amount?

Comment: Why keep the sqlite on the cloud? Will it be shared will all the users of the application? Check out this [Android database technique issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986734/which-android-data-storage-technique-to-use) raised as well as it lists all possible storage technologies that can be done in Android. Better yet, get a dedicated database that  you'll call thru a webservice.