# Data Storage for Android

Tags: android, database, cloud, sharedpreferences, storage

What are the different methods that can be used for data storage purposes in android? I have practiced SharedPreferences though it feels a bit complex to me as a beginner developer, does android provide a more clean and easy management of the storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through it, [Which Android Data Storage Technique to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986734/which-android-data-storage-technique-to-use) (It will be helpful to know more about various techniques).

[image]

Comment: link provided is very helpful.

Comment: Thank you @AmolNage

Comment: Thanks for the link. It explained the data storage options very clearly. 

Comment: Glad, it helped you. and thanks at the same time @AkshayVarma

Answer (score 1):

Pulled straight from Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

> Your data storage options are the following:
>
> **[Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)**
>
> Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
>
> **[Internal Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)**
>
> Store private data on the device memory.
>
> **[External Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)**
>
> Store public data on the shared external storage.
>
> **[SQLite Databases](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)**
>
> Store structured data in a private database.
>
> **[Network Connection](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw)**
>
> Store data on the web with your own network server.

Answer (score 0):

**SQLite** is a opensource **SQLite Database** data storage purpose. SQLIte database have different ways to store and retrieve data methods.

Here is the Tutorial for SQLite Database [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Otherwise, Refer the second SQLite Database Example [Android SQLite Tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial)

I will suggest to refer above tutorial. This will be help to beginner developer for android data storage management.

Answer (score 0):

Your data storage options are the following:

- Shared Preferences. 
  Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
- Internal Storage. 
  Store private data on the device memory.
- External Storage. 
  Store public data on the shared external storage.
- SQLite Databases. 
  Store structured data in a private database.
- Network Connection. 
  Store data on the web with your own network server.