# Storing a data - Benefit and cons of each storage types

Tags: android

I have this kind of data. This can be or don't be an array. Just for easy reference.

> ArrayName = Array1, Array2, Array3
>
> Array1 = abc, cde, fgh
>
> Array2 = abc, cde
>
> Array3 = abc, cde, fgh, ijk, lmn

So, what are the best method to store this kind of data.

If I want to

1. Add or delete Array1 and all things inside
2. Add or delete item in Array2(eg. adding fgh or remove cde)

Methods I discovered:

1. SharedPreference [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)
2. Arrays
3. SQLite [Android SQLite Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015731/android-sqlite-example)
4. Text file

Please share the pro and cons of why you choose the method.
Please also share if there are better ways to store this kind of data.

Kindly edit this if you found a better link or sample for other to reference.

Comment: **ArrayName = Array1, Array2, Array3**

this array is array of arrays ?

You want to save them permanently ? I have question because your option 2. is Arrays

Comment: @MishaAkopov Yes, they are arrays of arrays. Yes, to save it permanently.You can combine 2 and 4 also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Android Data Storage Technique to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986734/which-android-data-storage-technique-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are pros and cons for each solutions:

1) **SharedPreference**

You save simple key-value pairs here. So it is very hard to save array and complex structures in SharedPreference. So the solution will not work with arrays and arrays of arrays. It will be extremely(but not impossible) difficult to achieve what you want.

2) **Arrays**

Absolutely not! It is memory storage, so when you close app, or on process death, you will lose all data

3) **SqlLite**

I would add to this other Databases for android, like Realm.
Good solution. It is structured storage for collection of data. It will be very easy for storing/retrieving data when it is structured as rows. Furthermore you can delete rows easily. You don't have to read whole structure (other arrays) when you need particular row, or particular array (table in this case)

4) **TextFile**

I don't recommend to store in a text file, but it is possible to do so, you can serialize those arrays to text file, and deserialize. But every time you have to do this, and to read whole structure and parse it even if you want only e.g. Array2. It can be slow when your data becomes bigger.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, It is very detailed and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's incredibly hard to give advice with such vague requirements, you apparently have data structured as an array of arrays of strings, and you want to store it persistently on Android - and that's basically all we know.

In addition to the solutions mentioned, I would consider using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) to store this as JSON to disk. While read/write may not have optimal performance, it's very easy to model documents with things like arrays of arrays, and we have no way of knowing your performance requirements vs ease of use.

```
class MyData {
  public List<List<String>> data;
}
```

If you then have a MyData object, you could simply serialize it to a string, which could be written to a file on disk:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(myData);
```

This would produce something like

```
{
  "data": [
    ["abc", "cde", "fgh"],
    ["abc", "cde"],
    ["abc", "cde", "fgh", "ijk", "lmn"]
  ]
}
```

which could easily be written to disk using e.g. standard File and  [BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html). You can then read it back and deserialize using:

```
MyData myData = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyData.class);
```

Comment: Indeed, that is what I had using for now, but planning on learning the SQLite.