# Saving EditTexts on App close

Tags: java, android

on the homepage of my app i have edittexts that represent counters for each row in my list. whenever i change activity and return back to my main screen all the numbers disappear, the same happens when I close the app and open it again. How do i make the numbers stay?

My main activity where I call the row layout with the edittexts

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyAdapterInterface{

private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
public ListView list1;

//instantiating the database class
com.example.rory.dripdrop.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dripdrop.DBAdapter(this);
public MyActivity mMyActivity;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.data_list);
    db.open();

    mMyActivity = this;

    //button and listener for add activity
    Button addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Add.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //button and listener for delete activity
    Button deleteBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Delete.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //button and listener for update activity
    Button updateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);
    updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Update.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/AssignmentDB";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //handler function for custom adapter, found example online to help with this
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, db.getAllRecords(), mMyActivity);
            list1.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });

}


public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    //update list
    addData();
}

//refreshes data base when main page is resumed
public void addData()
{

    //handler function for custom adapter, found example online to help with this
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, db.getAllRecords(), mMyActivity);
            list1.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });

}


//chaning the running total
public void updateLitres(int value)
{
    EditText editLitres = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    //EditText myEditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);

    editLitres.setText(String.valueOf(value));
    //myEditText2.setText(String.valueOf(value));
}

public void updateCost(double value)
{
    EditText editCost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit2);
    String.format("%.2f", value);
    editCost.setText("€" + String.valueOf(value));
}

private class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    //private ArrayList<>

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        return null;
    }

}

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
}
```

My custom adapter for the rows

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

//public int counter = 0;
public ArrayList<Integer> counter;
public ArrayList<Integer> counter2;
private MyAdapterInterface mMyInterface;

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, MyAdapterInterface myInterface) {

    //instantiating the values
    super(context, cursor);
    this.context = context;
    this.mMyInterface = myInterface;

    //array to sort each value per row
    counter = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    counter2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //default all counters to 0
    for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
    {
        counter.add(0);
        counter2.add(0);
    }

}
Context context;


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

    //getting the first value for the custom row (the item name)
    TextView textViewItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    textViewItemName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));


    final int litres = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(2))));

    //editText for custom row
    final EditText runningTotal = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.runningTotal);

    //setting up the plus button
    final Button plusButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.plusButton);
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int counterPos;
        private int counter2;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code to change the value of the editText and the array, not working

            //cursor.getPosition() returns the position in the list
            counterPos = counter.get(cursor.getPosition());


            //increments the number at counterPos
            counterPos = counterPos + litres;

            //incrementing the edittext
            //counter2 = counter.get(cursor.getPosition());
            counter2++;

            //set the new value to the array position
            counter.set(cursor.getPosition(), counterPos);

            //changes the editText in middle of row
            runningTotal.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));

            //sends counterPos to the interface for the running total
            mMyInterface.updateLitres(counterPos);
            mMyInterface.updateCost(counterPos * 0.00488);
        }
    });

    //setting up the minus button
    final Button minusButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
    minusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        private int counterPos = 0;
        private int counter2;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            //code to change the value of the editText and the array, not working

            counterPos = counter.get(cursor.getPosition());


            //increments the number at counterPos
            counterPos = counterPos + litres;

            //incrementing the edittext
            //counter2 = counter.get(cursor.getPosition());
            counter2--;

            //set the new value to the array position
            counter.set(cursor.getPosition(), counterPos);

            //changes the editText in middle of row
            runningTotal.setText(Integer.toString(counter2));

            //sends counterPos to the interface for the running total
            mMyInterface.updateLitres(counterPos);
            mMyInterface.updateCost(counterPos * 0.00488);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look here You should take a look at the shared preferences, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html, I used this and helped me get through it, You need to save each edit text that you want to save. and as for each row I would suggest making an array or loop for saving the edit boxes in the rows

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into SharedPreferences, once you do you will basically be saving your values in SharedPreferences in an onPause() / onDestroy() method, and then in your onResume() / onCreate() methods you will retrieve the previously stored data

Edit:  You can retrieve a string from an EditText in the following way

```
String toStore = EditText.getText().toString();
```

and then store it

```
getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("KEY", toStore);
```

so...

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    String toStore = EditText.getText().toString();
    getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE",MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("KEY", toStore);
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    String toStore = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("KEY", "defaultStringIfNothingFound");
    EditText.setText(toStore);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have done some reading on the sharedPreferences but can seem to figure out how to add each edittext from the row in, can you help?

Comment: sorry to be a pain haha but i am struggling with this concept. so i should make an onPause function and add in the code above and then create an onResume function to call the toString variable to resort the values in all the edittexts?

Comment: The above will work for saving and then reloading them into the fields, you have to specify the fields they go in though.

Comment: and how would i do that for a list view?

Comment: You would have to loop through the list view and use listView.getChildAt(i);

Comment: thanks for all the help, i implemented the functions and tried making a loop but i just cant get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

didn't read your code bro, but answering in concern to your question title :

override onStop and save the data to Shared Preferences, its very easy to use:

```
//To save your data
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("name", "Elena");
editor.putInt("idName", 12);
editor.commit();

//to extract your data in onCreate or whenever you feel like:

SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
```

Comment: thanks but what i am having trouble with is adding each new row into the onPause state?

Comment: you can use onStop or onDestroy too

Comment: but when i add a new row into the app how do i make the code so that it will save that as well, without hard coding in the values like the example above

Comment: maybe an array of EditText references and then looping through them would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `onSavedInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods of activity !

So in `onSavedInstanceState` (called before your activity pauses) you may save your `EditText' values to the bundle,

And restore them back in `onRestoreInstance` state.

You can use the link by @Kaique for more reference,

and also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769864/826657 and all related answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the shared preferences, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html