# How to judge after onSaveInstanceState in Android Development?

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-dialog, dialogfragment

sometimes, i will get a

> java.lang.IllegalStateException Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState

when i try to show a `DialogFragment`.

so now the question is how i can write a if statement to judge current state before i involve the show method like this?

```
if(!isAfterOnSaveInstanceState()) 
    dialog.show(getSupportFragment(),"MY DIALOG");
```

because i notice that the `DialogFragment` own the method `dismissAllowingStateLoss()` but lack of a method to allow state loss when show, maybe the design of the `DialogFragent` want developers to judge before call `show` method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

`onSaveInstanceState()`: If called, this method will occur before `onStop()`. There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after `onPause()`.
you can check `isFinishing()` before show your `DialogFragment`

```
if(!isFinishing()) {
// your code goes here... 
}
```

more detail:[link-1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html),[link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769654/how-to-use-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate),[link-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177781/java-lang-illegalstateexception-can-not-perform-this-action-after-onsaveinstanc)