# How to save fragment state while navigating through activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

May be  the title of the question is not clear . Or I have failed to describe what I am looking for .

I have two activity in my app . Lets say their name is **"ActivityA"** and  **"ActivityB"** . Under "ActivityA" there are few fragments . Lets say their name is **"FragmentA"**  **"FragmentB"** **"FragmentC"**  **"FragmentD"** etc . The default fragment  is "FragmentA" , that means when the activity starts "FragmentA" starts .

Now , if I navigate to **"ActivityB"**  , and came back to **"ActivityA"** , it always open **"FragmentA"** . But what I want is if I navigate to **"FragmentB"** , and then navigate to **"ActivityB"** , and back to **"ActivityA"**  it starts **"FragmentA"** , but I want **"FragmentB"** to start ,in which I was beforer

Comment: It would be better if you provide some brief code

Comment: to navigate from Activity B to Activity A, do you start activity A using intent or use back button?

Comment: I am using back button

Comment: at what activity lifecycle are you adding the default fragments? or is the fragments added via xml?

Comment: defaults fragments are added in onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be restarting **ActivityA** from **ActivityB** via `startActivity()` instead of finishing **ActivityB**. If it is so, just finish your **ActivityB**. Then you will be on the last shown fragment in your **ActivityA**.

Or you can also use `onSaveInstanceState` method to keep trace of your `Fragments`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769864/2571277) can help you with this.

Or using following with your **ActivityA** can also solves your issue:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityA" android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think what you need to do is `startActivityForResult` when you call your *ActivityB*. When you press BackButton you provide your necessary information about the fragment to be called and catch these infos in *ActivityB*'s `onActivityResult` then navigate to the desired Fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method that returns the last visible fragment

```
 public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
        if(fragments != null){
            for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
                if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                    return fragment;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Create an instance of `Fragment` class and set it to null

```
Fragment lastVisibleFragment = null;
```

in `onPause` save the last fragment

```
  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
         lastVisibleFragment = getVisibleFragment();
    }
```

Then in `onResume()` add the last fragment you were in if not null

```
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(lastVisibleFragment !=null){    
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(yourFrameLayout, lastVisibleFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
       else{ //Add first fragment you were adding}
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your method . I have a navigation drawer in my app .  getVisibleFragment() returns my Navigation DrawerFragment