# Cant modify views in onCreate when passed savedInstanceState

Tags: android

I cant seem to be able to modify the view of my layouts after the first initialization of the android app in `onCreate(null)`, when I minimize the app and open it up again `onCreate(savedInstanceState)`, all my functions like `setText` don't seem to matter

[image]

```
package com.example.www.i_fucking_hate_java;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            // this will work
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText("Good afternoon");
            Log.d("Me", "Running 1 " + ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString());
        }
        else
        {
            // k so we have an old instance,
            // problem is now our "handles" to our EditTexts are useless

            // THIS WILL NOT WORK ??????????????????????????????????????????
            // the value returned by getText is correct, but the emulator display
            // does not change - also I hate android
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText("Good night");
            Log.d("Me", "Running 2 " + ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString());
        }

//        // this will work
//        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText("Good morning");
//        Log.d("Me", "Running 3 "  + ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString());
    }
}
```

## Why is my app stuck on "Good afternoon" and not displaying "Good night" as according to the logger?

Comment: Try use in following manner stack[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769654/how-to-use-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In default view state will save and restore in `onRestoreInstanceState`. as `onRestoreInstanceState` call after `onCreate` even you change your text in `onCreate` it's will change back to save state in `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Your solution is move your view restoration from `onCreate` to `onRestoreInstanceState`

When `onRestoreInstanceState` will call?

This method is called between **onStart()** and **onPostCreate(Bundle)**.

> As your activity begins to stop, the system calls the
>   onSaveInstanceState() method so your activity can save state
>   information with a collection of key-value pairs. **The default
>   implementation of this method saves transient information about the
>   state of the activity's view hierarchy, such as the text in an
>   EditText widget or the scroll position of a ListView widget**. Your app
>   should implement the onSaveInstanceState() callback after the
>   onPause() method, and before onStop(). Do not implement this callback
>   in onPause().

For more info see [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Where is the documentation that says "In default view state will save and restore in onRestoreInstanceState"

Comment: It's related to lifeCycle ( in your case activity lifeCycle) in case like rotation changed that activity must to destroy and recreate, all value will save in onSaveInstance and restore in onRestoreInstance, you can change this behave from manifest file.

Comment: thank you so much it finally worked - literally would never have solved it without your help (spent 6+ hours on this)

Comment: I'm glad to help you