# Determine if fragment restart is due to screen rotation or Viewpager swipe?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rotation, android-viewpager, android-configchanges

I have an `Activity` with `ViewPager`. the `ViewPager` have a lot of pages, Just like a book. Each fragment has `RecyclerViews` with a lot of content. The following is my use case

1 - When I swipe page, RecyclerView must start from the beginning of the list.
2. If I rotate my device, It should read from exact last position of where I left before rotation.

If I don't use any logic, 2nd scenario works perfectly. ie, rotation. But not the first scenario.

If I do some logic like below. Helps to achieve first scenario, But not the second scenario.

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
        mIsFirstTime = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            if (!mIsFirstTime) {
                mListView.scrollToPosition(0);                
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So My question is

> How can I determine a fragment restart is due to screen rotation or Viewpager swipe?

I already tried `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` . But it doesn't help me. Could you please help me

Comment: Let me correct, You have one activity with viewPager, And each page having its own fragment, a fragment having recyclerview?

Comment: @jiteshmohite I  have one activity with a view pager. this view pager have only one fragment with a recyclerview . the data will change according to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [a comment of OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495197/how-can-i-determine-a-fragment-restart-is-due-to-screen-rotation-or-viewpager-sw#comment87058879_50019641):

> My question is how I know that `onSaveInstanceState()` is called due to screen orientation change and not fragment restart

You can do that via [`Activity#isChangingConfigurations()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#ischangingconfigurations) API.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        if (isChangingConfigurations()) {
            // this callback is executed as a result of a configuration change (e.g. orientation change)
        } else {
            // no configuration change happens (e.g. a click on a home button would end up here)
        }
    }
```

Now you can save a boolean value into `Bundle outState` and appropriate setup UI after recreation:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("isConfigurationChange", isChangingConfigurations());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialization logics here

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            boolean isConfigurationChange = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isConfigurationChange");

            // if `onCreate` is called as a result of configuration change
            if (isConfigurationChange) {
                // view hierarchy is not yet laid out, have to post an action 
                listView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // we are guaranteed, that `listView` is already laid out
                        listView.scrollToPosition(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Note, that performing boolean value checking logics inside `onResume()` is a bug (pressing home button and navigating back to the app would result in scrolling to the top again, which is not desired). Instead `onCreate()` should be chosen as a correct callback.

Comment: Let me try this logic and let you know

Comment: That's for notifying that bug. Your answer is more relevance for my problem. but onSaveInstanceState is not calling when screen rotate. I am overriding onConfigurationChanged . anyway your logic is working. Let me check if there is any other bugs .

Comment: `but onSaveInstanceState is not calling when screen rotate` It should be called, check whether you have overriden flags in manifest.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" this is the only thing I added in the manifest

Comment: That's your issue. Remove that flags and correctly handle orientation changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can declare a variable and check the status to true on swipe action.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
// here assign the variable to true;
// This method will get called only after a swipe action is invoked on 
//viewpager.  
 }});
```

Inside your fragment check whether the variable *status is true*, if so it's not getting generated from orientation, then reset the *variable to false*.

Happy coding :)

Comment: I already tried that. It won't work. It should work inside individual fragment instance.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Fragment and View Pager make use of `onSaveInstanceState()` function and use That saved Instance to scroll to an old position.

> In cases where the UI data to preserve is simple and lightweight, you
>   might use onSaveInstanceState() alone to preserve your state data. In
>   cases where you have complex data that you want to preserve, you can
>   use a combination of ViewModel objects, the onSaveInstanceState()
>   method, and persistent local storage.

### REFER [Saving UI States](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states.html)

### EXAMPLE FOR USING `onSaveInstanceState()`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("position")){
                int positon = savedInstanceState.getInt("position",0);
                YOUR_RECYCLER_VIEW.scrollToPosition(positon);
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("position",YOUR_RECYLER_VIEW.getVerticalScrollbarPosition());
}
```

### Learn More Here

1. [How to use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16769654/how-to-use-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)
2. [Android Developers Official Documention](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

To know the pageChange of viewpage use

```
myViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        //Use your logic here.

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        //Use your logic here.

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        //Use your logic here.

        }
    });
```

Comment: onSaveInstanceState also call when screen orientation change, .My question is how I know that onSaveInstanceState is called due to screen orientation change and not fragment restart

Comment: Try using a flag for saving orientation and save it in the savedStateInstance Bundle

Comment: I tried that. But in my scenario i am using a viewpager. It will work for the first page. but when you scroll to next page it won't work.

Comment: I am looking for a particular answer,ie, How can I know the cause of a fragment restart. Is this because Orientation change or Viewpager swipe

Comment: @VinayakB Viewpager swipe can be obtained by adding using `addOnPageChangeListener()` function. Refer my updated answer

Comment: Use interface to acknowldge the Fragment inside the Listener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169757/discussion-between-vinayak-b-and-tomin-b).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you scrolling to zero position? mListView.scrollToPosition(0);

I think you can in onPause of fragment save current position of RecyclerView and then, after recreation - go to that position.

Comment: Consider this App is a book. So for every swipe to next page the user needs to read from the first line .that's why I am using scrollToPosition(0)