# Handle orientation change android

Tags: android, android-orientation, android-screen-support

I am having a requirement where there are several buttons in a activity, and clicking on one will change the background. The activity refreshes on orientation change. Then i included, `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"` 
which solves the problem, but i have separate screens for portrait and landscape modes, this saves the state and do not pick the layout for landscape when the orientation is changes. Please guide how i can change the orientation but still prevent the activity refresh and thus saving the clicked button and background color.

Answer (score 4):

dont use `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"`
and use onSaveInstanceState() for return color or resource id  of background and then check it in oncreate() for set background

this example help you 
[How to use onSavedInstanceState example please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can u plz guide with an example snippet?

Answer (score 3):

```
used this
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```