# NullpointerException While coming Back to Previos activity

Tags: android, orientation, back, asynctaskloader

**FirstActivity:**

```
// static so that it survives orientation change.  
private static int mSelectedItemPosition = -1; // -1 = Not selected

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mSelectedItemPosition != -1) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, null, MainActivity.this);
    }

    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, new ActionBar.OnNavigationListener()       {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    if(itemPosition == 0 || itemPosition ==1) {
        mSelectedItemPosition = 0;
        Bundle b = ...
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);
    }
    else if(itemPosition == 2) {
        mSelectedItemPosition = itemPosition;
        Bundle b = ...
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);
    }
    else {
        mSelectedItemPosition = itemPosition;
        Bundle b = ...
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(mSelectedItemPosition, b, MainActivity.this);
    }
    ...
}
```

From the first activity i am going to second activity. in second activity when i change the orientation and comes back to first activity by clicking system back button i am getting the following exception. if i come back normally with out changing the orientation i am not getting any exception.

```
**Exception Details:**

01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.schoolinsites.mcpss/com.schoolinsites.mcpss.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1996)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3393)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1178)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at com.schoolinsites.DataAccessLayer.GCCLoader.<init>(GCCLoader.java:22)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at com.schoolinsites.mcpss.MainActivity.onCreateLoader(MainActivity.java:352)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:500)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:509)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:563)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at com.schoolinsites.mcpss.MainActivity.CallInitLoader(MainActivity.java:371)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at com.schoolinsites.mcpss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:153)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4516)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1960)
01-31 02:59:20.810: E/AndroidRuntime(7165):     ... 12 more
```

from the exception details i came to know that the `Asynctaskloader` is giving `NullPointerException`.

Can anyone tell me how to solve  this problem? i am not able to understand why it happens when i come back by changing the orientation.

**Dataaccesslayer:**

```
public class GCCLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Item>> {


    private String Url, XmlRoles;
    private int selection;
    private List<Item> mData;

    public GCCLoader(Context context, Bundle extras) {
        super(context);

        this.Url = extras.getString(Constatnts.Url, null);
        this.selection =extras.getInt(Constatnts.selection,0);
        this.XmlRoles = extras.getString(Constatnts.xmlroles,"");

    }

    @Override
      public List<Item> loadInBackground() {
        // This method is called on a background thread and should generate a
        // new set of data to be delivered back to the client.
        List<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();
        VideoDal dal = new VideoDal();
        data.addAll(dal.GetGCC(selection, dal.GetDocument(Url, XmlRoles, null)));
        return data;
      }

      /********************************************************/
      /** (2) Deliver the results to the registered listener **/
      /********************************************************/

    @Override
      public void deliverResult(List<Item> data) {
        if (isReset()) {
          // The Loader has been reset; ignore the result and invalidate the data.
          releaseResources(data);
          return;
        }

        // Hold a reference to the old data so it doesn't get garbage collected.
        // We must protect it until the new data has been delivered.
        List<Item> oldData = mData;
        mData = data;

        if (isStarted()) {
          // If the Loader is in a started state, deliver the results to the
          // client. The superclass method does this for us.
          super.deliverResult(data);
        }

        // Invalidate the old data as we don't need it any more.
        if (oldData != null && oldData != data) {
          releaseResources(oldData);
        }
      }

      /*********************************************************/
      /** (3) Implement the Loader’s state-dependent behavior **/
      /*********************************************************/

      @Override
      protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (mData != null) {
          // Deliver any previously loaded data immediately.
          deliverResult(mData);
        }



        if (takeContentChanged() || mData == null) {
          // When the observer detects a change, it should call onContentChanged()
          // on the Loader, which will cause the next call to takeContentChanged()
          // to return true. If this is ever the case (or if the current data is
          // null), we force a new load.
          forceLoad();
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected void onStopLoading() {
        // The Loader is in a stopped state, so we should attempt to cancel the 
        // current load (if there is one).
        cancelLoad();

        // Note that we leave the observer as is. Loaders in a stopped state
        // should still monitor the data source for changes so that the Loader
        // will know to force a new load if it is ever started again.
      }

      @Override
      protected void onReset() {
        // Ensure the loader has been stopped.
        onStopLoading();

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'mData'.
        if (mData != null) {
          releaseResources(mData);
          mData = null;
        }


      }

      @Override
      public void onCanceled(List<Item> data) {
        // Attempt to cancel the current asynchronous load.
        super.onCanceled(data);

        // The load has been canceled, so we should release the resources
        // associated with 'data'.
        releaseResources(data);
      }

      private void releaseResources(List<Item> data) {
        // For a simple List, there is nothing to do. For something like a Cursor, we 
        // would close it in this method. All resources associated with the Loader
        // should be released here.

      }


    }
```

Comment: Try persisting your mSelectedItemPosition variable inside onSaveInstanceState() method, and restore it inside onCreate(). For more info, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please

Comment: Pleaee post DataAccessLayer.GCCLoader.

Comment: Do you have have made changes in manifest file?

Comment: Use configChanges:orientation in your manifest file.

Comment: i add configchanges for second activity.

Comment: i added the code - Aashir.

Comment: use android:configChanges="orientation" for all the activities