# Why should I override onSavedInstanceState for retrieve instance state in android?

Tags: android, oncreate

In onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState), there`s already super.onCreate(savedInstanceState).

API says it restores states when create activity after destroyed.

But I have to override onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState) for restore specific states.

Why?

What kind of informations are saved in savedInstanceState with method onCreate() and onSavedInstanceState()?

I'm so confused!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please for a good explanation of what you do in the functions when you override them

Answer (score 0):

By default, when your device changes configuration (for example, devices rotates, you changed language settings, etc.), your foreground `Activity` is recreated, and all you Activity data is lost. For example, if you have a member variable `mVariable` that was assigned some value, after configuration change you will lose its value. That's why you need to save important data to `savedInstanceState` and re-init it from `onCreate()` method. You simply check whether `savedInstanceState` is not `null`, and if so, you init your values from savedInstance, else - init with default values.

Further reading: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

onSaveInstanceState() is called before your activity is paused. So any info that it needs after it is potentially destroyed can be retrieved from the saved Bundle. The *Bundle* is a container for all the information you want to save. You use the put* functions to insert data into it. To get the data back out, use the get* functions just like the put* functions. The data is stored as a name-value pair. There isn't a specific use of this element, you can use it in any case (save a name, a number or whatever you need to have again when the use open again the app)