# android: data gets lost when phone changed to landscape mode of tic tac toe game

Tags: android, android-layout

android: data gets lost when phone changed to landscape mode of TIC-TAC-TOE game

I have created an android app it works perfectly fine,but when i change the position of my phone to landscape mode all the all data gets reset that is all the text on the buttons of the game gets replaced by blank values.

Since i am new to android programming i am unable to sort this problem,
please help. thank you.

I'm not posting the XML code and java code cause its very big,
if you want to see the XML code or java code,then please comment.

Comment: You need to look into savedInstanceState

Comment: thank you i will check it and notify you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `onSaveInstanceState` method. When that method is called, save the data you want to keep to the `bundle` object. Then in `onCreate` you should be checking if `bundle != null)`, and if that is true (meaning you saved stuff in the `onSaveInstanceState` method, update your variables based on values in the bundle.

From the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), you should avoid using the `android:configChanges` property:

> Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. Please read [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Comment: im new to android programming, so if you can elaborate your answer more then it would be helpful

Comment: Please see this Stack Overflow answer for an example of how to use `onSaveInstanceState` properly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6525808/2448305

Comment: thnx i will check it implement and if it works i will notify you

Comment: how to save 'int's or 'char's
for example i have saved my data into an variable 'a' which is an it so how to code to save it using your idea of putInt
please tell the complete code of saving that variable 'a'

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if this worked for you :)

Comment: i have a 3 dimensional array a(i.e. i have declared it
"char[][][] a=new char[3][3][3];"
this way
now i want to save it how do i do that

"outState.putCharArray("a", a);"

in this way?



)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding that you might have already handled the savedInstanceState, then include

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in the activity in android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

May be it case for activity reload

there is a way you can try:Simply add the "screenSize" attribute like I did below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

more details: about it
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: ok ,i am having same kind of problem before, as far as i remember this solved me. @Anuj

Comment: ok wait i have to see my code what i have done , currently i am out. will be back in 2 hours.