# android-how to save dada when activity re-created

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bundle

I'm moving from activity 1 to activity 2 and send some data via intent . 
It's ok and no problem ,but when I leave activity 2 and then come back , the intent is empty . For solving this problem I've tried  this code :

```
    @Override 
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("row_id", row_id);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int row_idss = savedInstanceState.getInt("row_id");
    Log.v("this","restore" + Integer.toString(row_idss));
}
```

I tried to save it before I leave the activity and retrieve it on re-open .anyway , It didn't work and didn't log it either.

I tried onPause and onResume , strangely they didn't call either . I used this code to make sure it runs

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.v("this","test");
}
```

nothing logged .
Could you help me to solve this problem ? I don't know what should I do to solve it

thanks so much

Comment: you can see the activity lifecycle about 
Recreating an Activity http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the calls:

`super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`
`super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);`

Check the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please), in this answer they're not using the method onRestoreInstanceState but just the onCreate to restore the data. You also could use onRestoreInstanceState if you need a different behaviour.