# Android restore listview content

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer, onbackpressed

I have got two activities. In first you can input jobname and job place into inputtext views. First activity contains also navigation-draver menu (appearing from left side of screen). After clicking "Searc" button, results are shown in listview in second activity. You can long-click on any listview item and then it will be added to navigation-drawer in first activity. You can go back to first activity by clicking "back" arrow. The problem is, that when I will go back to first activity, press "Search" button again and then go back to first activity again, the navigation drawer menu is empty again (all items, which were added on first try are deleted). How to fix that?

Here is pic with my activities (sorry for poor quality):

1- first activity; 2- navigation drawer in first activity with added items from second activity' listview; 3- second activity (listview with search results)
[image]

EDIT:
My code from two activities (without imports to shorten it a little):
First (main):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListviewActivity lv = new ListviewActivity();

    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;

    ArrayList<String> arrayFav = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayLin = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ImageView mImageViewLogo;
    private Button mButtonSzukaj;
    private EditText mEditTextPraca;
    private EditText mEditTextMiejsce;
    public static String nazwaStanowiska;
    public static String nazwaMiejscowosci;
    private Settings mSettings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_layout);


        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();

        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mImageViewLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewLogo);
        mButtonSzukaj = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSzukaj);
        mEditTextPraca = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPraca);
        mEditTextMiejsce = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMiejsce);

        final String mPrBefore = mEditTextPraca.getText().toString();
        final String mPrAfter = mPrBefore.trim();

        final String mMiBefore = mEditTextMiejsce.getText().toString();
        final String mMiAfter = mMiBefore.trim();

        mEditTextPraca.setText(mPrAfter);
        mEditTextMiejsce.setText(mMiAfter);

        mSettings = new Settings(this);

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(mAdapter.isEmpty()){
            arrayFav.add("Brak ofert");
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(null);
            mDrawerList.setOnItemLongClickListener(null);
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mButtonSzukaj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextPraca.getText().toString()) && (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextMiejsce.getText().toString()))) {
                    mEditTextPraca.setError("Pole obowiązkowe!");
                    mEditTextMiejsce.setError("Pole obowiązkowe!");
                    return;
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextPraca.getText().toString())) {
                    mEditTextPraca.setError("Pole obowiązkowe!");
                    return;
                } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextMiejsce.getText().toString())) {
                    mEditTextMiejsce.setError("Pole obowiązkowe!");
                    return;
                } else {
                    nazwaStanowiska = mEditTextPraca.getText().toString();
                    nazwaMiejscowosci = mEditTextMiejsce.getText().toString();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListviewActivity.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);

                    mSettings.setmText1(mEditTextPraca.getText().toString());
                    mSettings.setmText2(mEditTextMiejsce.getText().toString());
                    mSettings.save();
                }
            }
        });
        readPreferences();
    }

    protected void readPreferences(){
        mEditTextPraca.setText(mSettings.getmText1());
        mEditTextMiejsce.setText(mSettings.getmText2());
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                ArrayList<String> passedText = data.getStringArrayListExtra("text");
                ArrayList<String> passedLink = data.getStringArrayListExtra("link");
                //arrayFav.clear();
                //arrayLin.clear();
                arrayFav.addAll(passedText);
                arrayLin.addAll(passedLink);
                addDrawerItems();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.podziel_sie_opinia) {
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:661249888"));
            mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Uważam, że aplikacja...");
            startActivity(mIntent);
            return true;
        }

        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

        private void addDrawerItems() {

            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayFav);
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tu pojawi się kliknięta oferta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    /*Intent myBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.onet.pl"));
                    startActivity(myBrowserIntent);*/


                    Intent myBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(arrayLin.get(position)));
                    myBrowserIntent.putExtra("paramPosition", position);
                    startActivity(myBrowserIntent);
            }
        });


        mDrawerList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usunięto z ulubionych!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if(mAdapter.isEmpty()){
                    arrayFav.add("Brak ofert");
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });


    }

    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Twoje oferty");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

and the second one (listview with results):

```
public class ListviewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    int global_position =0;
    boolean longClick = false;
    static String wybranaOferta = "";
    ArrayList<String> choosedOffer = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> choosedLink = new ArrayList<String>();
    MainActivity mainActiv;
    static List<String> mLista = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> positionArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    static List<String> mListaTest1 = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> mListaTest2 = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> mListaLinki = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> mListaNazwy = new ArrayList<>();
    static List<String> mListaFirmy = new ArrayList<>();

    private JobListAdapter mAdapter;
    public Elements jobName, jobName2, jobNameComp, jobName2Comp;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    private Context context;

    public ArrayList<String> workList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> companyList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> jobList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private JazzyListView mListView;
    public String doURLpraca = MainActivity.nazwaStanowiska;
    public String doURLmiejsce = MainActivity.nazwaMiejscowosci;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);

        mListView = (JazzyListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        mListView.setTransitionEffect(new FanEffect());
        mListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
        //Progress bar
        mListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wyszukiwanie ofert...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        new NewThread().execute();
        mAdapter = new JobListAdapter(this, jobList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent myBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mListaLinki.get(position)));
                myBrowserIntent.putExtra("paramPosition", position);
                startActivity(myBrowserIntent);
            }
        });

        mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    choosedOffer.add(mListaTest1.get(position).toString());
                    choosedLink.add(mListaLinki.get(position).toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dodano do ulubionych!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
        });
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ListviewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("text", choosedOffer);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("link", choosedLink);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            String doURLwork = mainActiv.nazwaStanowiska;
            String doURLplace = mainActiv.nazwaMiejscowosci;

            Document doc, doc2;
            Elements classs, lins;
            String uerele;
            try {
                doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.infopraca.pl/praca?q=" + doURLwork + "&lc=" + doURLplace)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();
                doc2 = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://www.pracuj.pl/praca/" + doURLwork + ";kw/" + doURLplace + ";wp")
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0").get();

                //Oferty
                jobName = doc.select("h2.p-job-title a[href]"); //Infopraca
                jobName2 = doc2.select("h2.offer__list_item_link a[href]");  //pracuj.pl

                //Firmy
                jobNameComp = doc.select("h3.p-name.company a[href]"); //Infopraca
                jobName2Comp = doc2.select("h3.offer__list_item_link a[href]");  //pracuj.pl

                //Oferty pracy
                //Infopraca
                mListaTest1.clear();
                for (Element jobNames : jobName) {
                    mListaTest1.add(jobNames.text() + "\n");
                }

                //Pracuj.pl
                for (Element jobNames2 : jobName2) {
                    mListaTest1.add(jobNames2.text() + "\n");
                }
                if(mListaTest1.size()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zmień parametry wyszukiwania!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //--------------------------------------------------

                //Firmy
                //Infopraca
                mListaTest2.clear();
                for (Element jobNames : jobNameComp) {
                    mListaTest2.add(jobNames.text() + "\n");
                }

                //Pracuj.pl
                for (Element jobNames2 : jobName2Comp) {
                    mListaTest2.add(jobNames2.text() + "\n");
                }

                //Linki do ofert
                //Infopraca
                for (Element link : jobName) {
                    mListaLinki.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
                }

                //Pracuj.pl
                for (Element link : jobName2) {
                    mListaLinki.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
                }

                //Łączenie wyników - oferta + nazwa firmy
                jobList.clear();
                for(int i=0; i<mListaTest1.size(); i++){
                    jobList.add(mListaTest1.get(i)+"\n"+mListaTest2.get(i));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some actual code/screenshots? May help with debugging this with you :).

Comment: I haven't gone through your entire code. But looks like you need to return "true" in your setOnItemLongClickListener() (in ListviewActivity). Returning "false" means you're not consuming the long click event. You should probably check at other places as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the first activity may be destroyed and recreated each time you go back to it. You might have to save list view items in activity's

> onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)

method and load them again in onCreate. A simple example can be found in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please)

Or, you can just use fragments instead of two activities.

EDIT:

It seems like onSaveInstanceState only works when the activity is being closed by force, and it's philosophy is that onDestroy() method is not a safe place to save your data since it might not get called for various reasons.

The easiest way to do this is to use fragments instead of separate activities. The list adapter should be a member of activity and instead of opening a new activity, a [fragment transaction](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) would take place.

Using the [back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) of fragment manager, the back button navigation will also be no problem and it would return the app to its initial state. Since the list is a field of the activity it can be easily shared between the fragments and it would not change due to fragment transactions.

Comment: Hey I found info, that onSaveInstanceState works only when app is stopped accidentally or something. It doesn't work with pressing "back" button.