# Using onSaveInstanceState during orientation change?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

*First thing; I'm pretty much brand new to all this.*

I've built a basic calculator but I lose the data when switching orientation (such as typing the number 9 then it going blank when switched to landscape).

I've already looked and found this:
[How to use onSavedInstanceState example please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please/6525808#6525808)
, but I'm unsure how to implement it into my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView _screen;
private String display = "";
private String currentOperator = "";
private String result = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _screen = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    _screen.setText(display);



}

private void updateScreen(){
    _screen.setText(display);
}
```

Can anyone help? An example using my piece would be perfect. Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for onConfigurationChange() method ?

Comment: I apologise but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well show the code for your onSaveInstanceState. Show what you tried.

Comment: Typing the number 9? Where do you type in?

Comment: `private TextView _screen;`. Dont call a TextView a screen. Better; private TextView textView;

Comment: There's more code to it (calculator functions ect).
I honestly believed that the above was it for onSaveInstanceState. I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: I think I've discovered my problem; I've been using a TextView rather than a TextField (editText) and I was unable to reconcile the string names in my head.