# my table layout data is getting cleared(recreating the app) on screen rotation in android

Tags: android

Description :

I have created an android app on launching the activity ,i will add some elements in tableLayout from drop down and i will have total count of those elements at bottom.

Issue Facing : When i rotate my screen , the table layout contents or data is getting cleared and re launched . Can anyone get me the solution to keep my table data on roatating the screen also.

Comment: save data on `onSaveInstanceState` method. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6525808/3425390).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating your activity tag in manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

I added following properties in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ShoppingListActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
```