# How to use onSavedInstanceState with widgets?

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

I'm learning about screen rotation for an App, I came across this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525698/how-to-use-onsavedinstancestate-example-please#) and I tried it.

My issue is that when I try this with a Button widget, it's text is still blank. When the button is clicked a date picker dialog appears to pick a date. But if the screen is rotated after the selection is made, the previously selected date is lost.

This is my code:

```
startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        setDate(startDate);
    }
});

public void setDate(final Button B)
{
    final Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    day = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    year = calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    DatePickerDialog pickDate = new DatePickerDialog(add_event.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            calender.set(i,i1,i2);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            String dateString = dateFormat1.format(calender.getTime());
            B.setText(dateString);
        }
    },year,month,day);
    pickDate.show();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putString("startDate", startDate.getText().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    startDate.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("startDate"));
}
```

Here are some images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the version of `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` with just one argument. The other is for when you have an attribute set in the manifest for the activity to persist across reboots.